# How to scale my socket server that ran out of CPU cycle?

Tags: sockets, apache-spark, rabbitmq, load-balancing

I have a legacy/typical socket server that processes a job and returns the result to some 100k of socket clients synchronously. Currently it can process only some 100 requests/ms and hence the requests are delayed. what is the best way to scale this ?

```
1) Add more servers and use a load balancer upfront ?
2) Use some queuing solution ( activemq, rabbitmq ?) which will provide load balancing plus messaging ?
3) Will apache spark or something help here ?
```

The clients are designed to contact a single IP/VIP/host/master.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Hardware/server configuration is off-topic

Comment: So you already serve like 300000 requests/s ("some 100 requests/ms")? Not bad, btw! Then you must be sitting in a data center somewhere, at the end of a light cable? Anyway, analogy: I have a car that goes 350 km/h. How do i get it to go 450? a) nitro b) twin turbo or c) bigger engine?